# Count number of times a term appears in an array of lists

Tags: google-sheets

I have a question the count function. Lets say a have a single column of data coming in from a google form. Its going to have 3 data inputs coming in from each response of the form. The possible responses are from "A" to "Z", but each response can only be three of those choices. 
Ex.

```
A,B,N
B,C,Z
X,T,H
X,E,B
Y,W,J
```

Is there a function to count the number of times a said input appeared in the the column? To tell me the number of times an A appeared, a B appeared, a C and so on?

Comment: This seems very closely related to this: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/89413/354

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways, but the easiest is to use [`countif`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) with wildcards:

```
=countif(A1:A, "*X*")
```

Here `*` matches any number of characters, so `*X*` matches any string containing X.